# Is there any way to increase the icon size of the tkinter gui window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, icons

I chnaged the icon of my tkinter gui but now when I look at it , it looks a little small in size . So, is there any way to increase the size of the window icon ?

Comment: Can you show us your code, it will be easier to help you

Comment: in question show image with icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re talking about the main window (top level) 
You can use

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry(‘500x500’) #px
```

Otherwise you can change the width,height arguments